# Speed of different constructs in programming languages (Java/C#/C++/Python/…)

Tags: c#, java, algorithm, performance

My boss just told me that he learned about fast VB6 algorithms from a book and that the shortest way to write things is not necessarily the fastest (e.g. builtin methods are sometimes way slower than selfwritten ones because they do all kinds of checking or unicode conversions which might not be necessary in your case).

Now I wonder, is there a website with info on fast different constructs are in various languages, esp. Java/C#/Python/… (also C++ but there are so many compilers which probably differ a lot).

E.g. is there a difference between

```
if (a()) b();
```

and

```
a() && b();
```

Another example: is `a = a * 4` maybe compiled to the same code as `a <<= 2`?

I could test this myself, of course, writing both then running them 100000 times and comparing the runtime, but I'd also like to learn about new ways to write things, maybe even things that I hadn't considered before. Thanks for your answers!

Comment: unless you're working on very special kind of hardware (like tiny embedded Java SmartCard) or very special algorithms (like, say, cryptographic APIs) there's not much point in worrying about this.

Comment: In addition to the answers so far: The cleanest, shortest and most maintainable way to write it IS the best way to write is, despite any hypothetical performance differences, unless of course is has truly horrbile performance characteristics (e.g. the naive quicksort in Haskell, which does lots and lots of list concatenation).

Comment: There's much more to a language than boolean algebra and basic decision constructs.  The framework for .NET 4 is scary enough, much less compared to 2-3 others.  Are you talking C++ managed or unmanaged?  lol, people write this stuff not machines.  You'd be lucky to find correct documentation, much less cross framework Big-O charts.  Welcome to reality my friend.

Comment: `a <<= 2` is not `a * a`, it is `a * 4`

Comment: I made a mistake there … of course, leftshift by *n* is multiplication by *2^n*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> is there a difference between `if (a()) b();`  and `a() && b();` ?

Yes, readability. The first is far more clear about the intent.

> Is `a = a * 4` maybe compiled to the same code as `a <<= 2` ?

Most likely yes.  But even if they ended up as different CPU instructions the difference in time would be very small, and dependent on the instructions before and after.

Micro-Optimizing for modern CPU's is

- very difficult
- mostly futile
- often contrary to what used to be an 'optimization' 10+ years ago.

In conclusion, write *readable* code first. When you do have a performance problem, profile and measure first.

As an Application Developer you should worry about using the right algorithms, like not reading a collection more than needed etc. But on the instruction/statement level, there are too many layers (C# Compiler, IL Compiler, Optimizers, pipelined CPU) between you and what actually gets executed.

Comment: @Ben: You're right, I overlooked that (: But it doesn't really affect the core of the Question or Answer.

Comment: Well now at least some hypothetical future reader won't come and apply an erroneous optimization because they saw you agreed with it.

Answer (score 11):

I would say these are likely to be the kind of micro-optimizations that wouldn't make a difference and aren't worth the effort.

Algorithm choice does matter, but the books you should be reading should be more like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849967202).

If you really want to see whether the bit hacks you've cited make a difference, I'd recommend getting a performance baseline on the code you want to change first.  Make your changes and remeasure performance the same way.  If you get a result that says it's worth it, by all means continue.

You're better off profiling your code and finding out where the slowest part of your code lives and where the most work is being done.  Guessing rarely works when optimizing.

Comment: I don't think his boss was referring to these optimizations.

Comment: The boss might have been thinking about something else, but s/he's planted a bad seed with this suggestion.  The answer is still "don't do it."

Comment: Yeah I own Cormen's book. I also know that readability goes first. Still …  look at this, for example: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html There are absolutely amazing algorithms up there! The question was meant more for my learning and understanding …

Answer (score 8):

Don't be bothered by such microoptimizations. They won't give you anything in performance aspect.

If you have performance issue, find the bottleneck and optimise it.

Comment: I didn't give this -1, but the first paragraph is incorrect. Micro-optimisations frequently give you significant performance improvements and are important in many contexts. Of course, the second paragraph is still totally correct....

Comment: @mikera Micro-optimization/tweaks that come about as a *result* of profiling, hot-spot detection, and informed optimization decisions, perhaps. But all the other micro-optimizations -- say the ones that *don't* contribute to any hot-spots -- are likely entirely worthless and perhaps even counter-optimizations.

Answer (score 4):

Always do your best to create good, clean, efficient code. This can mean micro-optimizations (like use stringbuilder instead of adding strings, don't use regexps if they are not necessary, stuff like that, don't listen to people who say these are pointless: if you write bad code and don't even care, the JITter won't help you) or bottleneck optimizations (don't select * from an entire table, use multithreading). The managed environment will do the rest. CPU intensive stuff will never be as performant as nonmanaged code, but there are many advantages, too, that's why most people like to use them. If you want really fast pieces of code, do it in C, assembly or hardware. Most of today's business applications aren't CPU intensive, as in GUI's, webservices, databases, disk usage, they all involve a lot of waiting and idle CPU.

As for your question: if (a()) b(); and a() && b(); are completely the same, there's no optimization here. a * a and a<<2 are not the same, the latter is a*4.

Comment: Choosing to use a string builder/buffer rather than the copying that concatenation and not using regex are differences in amortized algorithmic complexity, not micro-optimisations.

Comment: @Pete Kirkham Actually, this choice of StringBuilder is often an example of a micro-optimization in some environments. Modern Java, for instance, will turn concats into a SB underneath if it feels that it is important. I *only* use StringBuilder where using such would *actually make the code cleaner* or where *it just makes sense* -- e.g. something that "fits" like a template generator. Otherwise, I *have never noticed* a problem with "normal string concatenation".

Comment: @pst I haven't tried 7, but it is not the case up to Java 6 that the compiler would do that for concating a string in several statements, storing the intermediates, which is the case the optimisation applies. For a single statement `String z = a + b + c`, it very often would, but `String z = a + b; if (x) z = z + c;` wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is very old question but there is also one aspect, that nobody mention:

**operator overload**

`a *= 4`, `a = a * 4`, `a = a << 2` and `a <<= 2` will do the same only for plain integers without operator overload.

In all mentioned languages (except Java), you can easily add operator oveload and each of these forms can have completely different result. If you are using integers and later decide to use floats, you can have problems with some operators, because they are not defined (`<<`, `<<=`), etc.

On the other hand in case of plain integers, many forms will probably generate completely the same machine code. On some platforms, machine code will not involv multiplication nor left shift at all - e.g. c++ compilers on x64 tend to generate `lea eax, [4*rdi]` for all cases. So the compiler will outsmart you.